# Calculate Not Renewals from historical data

Tags: mysql, historical-db

I Have to calculate no of users not renewed on particular day from historical data.I have table **payment** containing columns : **userid,product,payment_type,subscription_date,end_date** where **payment_type** can be Annual,Quarter,Month. This table have 20000 historical data.And i have to fetch all records from starting and calculate on first subscription_date how many registered users are not renewed. and same for all subscription_date

**Table Schema**
[image: 1]
**Sample Input**[image]

**Output**
Fetch all data and calculate no of registered users that does not renewed on subscription_date.

Comment: If you expect us to do your job at least do your part properly and provide exact table schema with datatypes, sample data and desired output based on that data. Better yet go ahead and create [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/) to help those who wants to help you.

Comment: What constitutes a non renewed user based on presented data?